# I2c between beaglebone black and STM32F4-discovery

Tags: gpio

I'm planning to connect my beaglebone black to stm32f4-discovery. The purpose is to test i2c library of beaglebone black written in c. But I'd like to check if I'd fry my boards. Would it be okay to connect i2c pins of two boards? Or can you connect 'gpio out' pin of stm32f4 directly to 'gpio in' pin of beaglebone?

Comment: Check the voltages. And don't forget connect grounds.

Comment: they use 3.3v. But would I break them, because of short? Also the beaglebone black's gpio pins are tolerant under 6mA. So large current can break it. Would I need resistor between the two boards?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, as long as they both support the same voltage (usually 5 or 3.3 V). I2C pins are configured as open-drain. They would simply float unstably (tri-stated) were it not for the pull-ups which ensure that the pins stay HIGH when no device on the bus is pulling them LOW. When the pins are eventually driven LOW, the pull-ups (4.7k is good) will also limit any current flowing into the pins to safe levels, well below 6mA.

```
5 V / 4.7k = 1.06 mA
3.3 V / 4.7k = 0.7 mA
```

Dont forget to connect their GNDs together for a common reference point.